# Rails DB error in column in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When you try to go to the page associated with this controller did these mistakes . Help to solve my mistake . Thank you

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18c92814a94974f5dbe8b78450076f27 its my log

## views/ua/rates.html.erb

```
        <div class="content_name">
            <h3>Тарифні плани</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
                    <%= render :partial => 'ua_rates/ua_rates_index'%>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 col-sm-11 col-sm-push-1 col-xs-12">
                <h4>​До кожного тарифного плану входить:</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>24/7 доступ до web APIs</li>
                    <li>Необмежена кількість внесення змін до дизайну Пассу</li>
                    <li>До 10 геоміток для кожного Пассу</li>
                    <li>Необмежена кількість Email повідомлень</li>
                    <li>Необмежена кількість Push повідомлень на екран клієнта</li>
                    <li>Можливість розповсюдження за допомогою QR-коду та web-лінків</li>
                    <li>Відслідковування статистики по кожному Пассу</li>
                    <li>Можливість створення індивідуального тарифу</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## ua_controller

```
  class UaController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @contact = Contact.new
      if @contact.save
        redirect_to :root
        ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now   
       end
    end

    def solution
      @contact = Contact.new
      if @contact.save
        redirect_to :root
        ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
      end
    end

    def rates
      @uarates = UaRate.all
      @contact = Contact.new
      if @contact.save
        redirect_to :root
        ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
      end
    end

    def contact
      @contact = Contact.new
      if @contact.save
        redirect_to :root
        ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
```

## _ua_rates_index.html.erb

```
        <% @uarates.each do |x| %>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-0 col-xs-12">
                <div class="dashed_container">
                    <h5><%= x.title %></h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= x.price %></li>
                        <li><%= x.card_type %></li>
                        <li><%= x.card_limit %></li>
                        <li><%= x.sms_count %></li> 
                    </ul>
            <a><%= link_to 'Обрати', new_rate_form_path, :class => "content_button_blue"%></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

## ua_rates_controller

```
class UaRatesController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @uarates = UaRate.all
 end

 def show
   @uarate = UaRate.find params[:id]
 end
end
```

## schema.rb

```
create_table "ua_rates", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title",      limit: 255
t.string   "card_limit", limit: 255
t.string   "card_type",  limit: 255
t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
t.string   "price",      limit: 255
t.string   "sms_count",  limit: 255
end


create_table "uas", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

## ua_rate.rb

```
class UaRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ua
  has_many :rate_forms
end
```

## ua.rb

```
class Ua < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :ua_rates
end
```

Comment: Your gist is about "en" but your code is about "ua". Also, I don't see a `ua_id` in your `ua_rates` table to support that `belongs_to :ua` in `UaRate`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iLucker93/8a98698e13471d0a247d34614ab9b75d   updated